# popd back to other directory and simultaneously pushd current dir

Tags: bash

A lot of times I'm working between two directories. While it's nice to be able to

```
/working/dir/1 $     pushd /other/working/dir
/other/working/dir $ do something
/other/working/dir $ popd
/working/dir/1 $     do something else
/working/dir/1 $     pushd /other/working/dir
```

It would be nice if the popd call pushed `/other/working/dir` onto the stack, so that I could just call popd back and forth between two directories.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 6):

The `-` parameter to the `cd` command is an alias for the previous directory.
So `cd -` is like a back-button for cd that works for exactly one step in the history.

Using `cd -` repeatedly toggles between two directories.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `popd`, use `pushd` with no arguments. That will *swap* the top 2 directories on the stack and cd to the new top directory.

Ref [6.8.1 Directory Stack Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins)